# comparar tablas y calcular tiempo de tardanza

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Quiero comparar dos tablas para sacar el tiempo de tardanza. Resulta que tengo dos tablas CRONOGRAMA y CHECKINOUT. En la primera estan los datos de HORARIO por así decirlo, y en el segundo estan los datos de su registro, es decir la hora que marca y el tipo (si es Entrada registrara I y si es Salida registrara O). Lo que necesito es comparar las horas entre estas dos tablas y saber que usuario llego tarde y en que fecha.

Los campos son los siguientes:

```
CREATE TABLE CRONOGRAMA(
    IDUSUARIO   INT,
    FECHA       DATE, 
    HORAENTRADA TIME(0),
    HORASALIDA  TIME(0),
    TIPO        CHAR
);
CREATE TABLE CHECKINOUT(
    IDUSUARIO   INT,
    REGISTRO    DATETIME,
    TIPO        CHAR
);
```

Esta en SQLSERVER, y la verdad ni siquiera sé por donde empezar, agradecería su apoyo

Comment: Podrias poner datos de ejemplo para poder ayudarte y un poco mejor la estructuras de tus tablas

Comment: En CRONOGRAMA por ejemplo estan los horarios fijos de los usuarios: Por Ejemplo: 123, 2019-09-20, 07:30, 14:30, null.... mientras que en CHECKINOUT estan los registros que se hacen diario, por ejemplo si un usuario se registro hoy y en este momento:123, 2019-09-20, 08.58.23.0000,I...... es decir lo que yo necesito es que segun la tabla de registro (CHECKINOUT) Compare con CRONOGRAMA para ver si hoy llego tarde o no.

Comment: Y como sabes que llego tarde o no? debe de haber una condición, no se por ejemplo para saber si llego tarde o no con la tabla crogograma no? en este caso 07:30 ah esa hora debio de entrar no?

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer puedes hacerlo crando un procedure o declarando una función, mira este link donde te explica como realizar cada uno y su uso.
https://elbauldelprogramador.com/plsql-procedimientos-y-funciones/

Comment: El registro de `CHECKINOUT` ¿te dice si se trata de una entrada o una salida?  Por el contrario, si solo son fecha+hora en que se marcó una tarjeta, ¿Que pasa si hay registros incompletos? Por ej. de marcó la entrada y no la salida. ¿Hay un proceso que agregué registros automáticos de cierre?

Comment: Exacto, la tabla CRONOGRAMA, contiene una lista de fechas con hora de entrada y hora salidad en la que el usuario debe llegar, la tabla CHECKINOUT, es la tabla de registro, es decir tengo que comparar si hoy se registro y si hoy llego tarde, el campo CHAR de la tabla CHECKINOUT, tiene el caracter de entrada o salida, es decir si marco entrada tendra 'I' si marco salida tendra 'O'

Comment: Cuando un usuario marca su entrada en la tabla CKECKINOUT, se registro es el siguiente: por ej. 1233,2019-09-20, 13.12.23.0000, I. Bien ahora si marca su salida es la siguiente: 1233, 2019-09-20, 13.12.23.0000, O.

Comment: Entonces, estos registros tengo que comparar con la lista de de fechas y horas que estan en la tabla CRONOGRAMA, para ver si ese dia marco y si llego tarde

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo algo, segun lo que entendi, si no es, se puede ir modificando.

```
DECLARE @CRONOGRAMA TABLE 
(
IDUSUARIO INT,
FECHA DATE, 
HORAENTRADA  TIME,
HORASALIDA TIME,
TIPO CHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO @CRONOGRAMA VALUES( 123, '2019-09-20', '07:30', '14:30', null)
DECLARE @CHECKINOUT TABLE
(
IDUSUARIO INT,
REGISTRO DATETIME,
TIPO CHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @CHECKINOUT VALUES( 123, '2019-09-20 08:58:23:000', 'I')

 SELECT CASE WHEN P.HORAENTRADA<CAST(C.REGISTRO AS time) THEN 'Tarde por ' +CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,P.HORAENTRADA,CAST(C.REGISTRO AS TIME)) AS nvarchar(100)) +' Minutos' 
        ELSE 'A tiempo' END  FROM @CRONOGRAMA P
 INNER JOIN @CHECKINOUT C ON C.IDUSUARIO=P.IDUSUARIO
```

Declare las tablas como variables para no crearlas, lo que esto nos da es si llego tarde en este caso entiendo que se registra en cronograma que debe de entrar a las 7:30 pero el llega a las 8:58 entonces esta llegando tarde y lo que hace este ejemplo que te pongo es decir por cuantos minutos llego tarde. si es algo asi lo que buscas podemos modificarlo.
Saludos

Comment: pero me encantaria que compare en una fecha especifica

Comment: Y cual seria esa fecha especifica, no seria la de HoraEntrada entoces?